# Cannot Create an instance of the abstract class on interface 'HttpRequest'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> Cannot Create an instance of the abstract class on interface 'HttpRequest'

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa parte do meu código:

```
class FakeContext
{
    public static HttpContext FakeHttpContext()
    {
        var httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://stackoverflow/", "");
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        var httpResponse = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
        var httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);

        var sessionContainer = new HttpSessionStateContainer("id", new SessionStateItemCollection(),
                                                new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(), 10, true,
                                                HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect,
                                                SessionStateMode.InProc, false);

        httpContext.Items["AspSession"] = typeof(HttpSessionState).GetConstructor(
                                    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                                    null, CallingConventions.Standard,
                                    new[] { typeof(HttpSessionStateContainer) },
                                    null)
                            .Invoke(new object[] { sessionContainer });

        return httpContext;
    }
}
```

oque estou fazendo errado ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está confundindo [`System.Web.HttpRequest`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest?view=netframework-4.8) do **.Net Framework** com o [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest?view=aspnetcore-2.2) do **.Net Core**.

O segundo é uma classe abstrata e como o erro informa, você não pode instancia-la. Você pode usar Injeção de Dependência para utiliza-lo com o [`IHttpContextAccessor`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.ihttpcontextaccessor?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Mas pro seu caso, pra fazer um `request`, [veja o exemplo da própria Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Acredito que você seguiu algum exemplo do .Net Framework mas em um projeto que utiliza o .Net Core.

Abaixo um exemplo simplificado:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

    public HomeController(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> FakeHttpContext()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://stackoverflow/");
        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        //Restante do seu código...

        return response;
    }
}
```